# In Odoo 8 Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I've added a new field `discount` in `account.invoice.line`

```
_inherit = "account.invoice.line"

discount = fields.Float(string='Discount (%)',
                        digits=(16, 10),
                        # digits= dp.get_precision('Discount'),
                        default=0.0)
```

now logicaly `price_subtotal = price_unit* qty *(1-discount)` of each line.
in the other class `account.invoice` i've idited the function that calculate `amount_total` and `amount_tax`

```
_inherit = "account.invoice"

@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal' ,'tax_line.amount')
def _compute_amount(self):
    disc = 0.0
    for inv in self:
        for line in inv.invoice_line:
            disc += (line.quantity * line.price_unit) * (line.discount) / 100
    self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
    self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount*self.change_rate for line in self.tax_line)
    self.amount_discount = disc
    self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax
```

The problem is if i change the value of discount in some line, the amoun_tax of the invoice does not change

thanks in advance

Comment: There already should be a discount field on `account.invoice.line` with this functionality. Why do you want to add it again?

Comment: @CZoellner I use two kind of discount, discount on total  amount and discount per line

Comment: The first discount that already exists, I headed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hard search and try, i've found why the `amount_tax` not calculating correctely, and i've edited just a line that calculates the taxes in the same function  `_compute_amount` of `account.invoice` class

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal',  'invoice_line.discount', 'tax_line.amount')
def _compute_amount(self):
    disc = 0.0
    for inv in self:
        for line in inv.invoice_line:
            disc += (line.quantity * line.price_unit) * (line.discount) / 100
    self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
    self.amount_tax = sum(line.price_subtotal*(sum(tax.amount for tax in line.invoice_line_tax_id)) for line in self.invoice_line)
    self.amount_discount = disc
    self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *discount* field into *@api.depends* so when you update discount field, your method will be execute and calculate amount as per your logic.

Try with following code:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('invoice_line.price_subtotal' ,'tax_line.amount', 'invoice_line.discount')
def _compute_amount(self):
    disc = 0.0
    for inv in self:
        for line in inv.invoice_line:
            disc += (line.quantity * line.price_unit) * (line.discount) / 100
    self.amount_untaxed = sum(line.price_subtotal for line in self.invoice_line)
    self.amount_tax = sum(line.amount*self.change_rate for line in self.tax_line)
    self.amount_discount = disc
    self.amount_total = self.amount_untaxed + self.amount_tax
```

Comment: Add discount field into @api.depends, does not working

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana Have you compare code ? What is different between your answered code and my answered code ? I see both are same. :D

Comment: The difference between your answer and mine in how to calculate the `amount_tax`